# iOS - disable touches through a view on map

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to disable touches through views on the map. Right now when I touch a view it's transferring the touch through to the map. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you explain your view hierarchy a little more? Do you want a view that’s a subview of the map to receive touches but not pass them through? Or do you want to disable touches to the map entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and disable userInteraction on all the subviews of your view.

```
NSArray *subviews = yourView.subviews;

for (UIView *view in subviews) {
    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

I haven't tested with a mapview, but I've used this setup before to disable touches on whole views and just re-enable touch for the couple of items I want (read-only mode basically). Hope this helps.